# SharePoint 2013 search results don't show some document sets in Autocomplete/Suggetion

Tags: search-results, search-scope, fast-search

I tried to search for a title string. I have more than 10 docuements setsin document library which title starts with string I did search for. But it doesn't show all document sets in Autocomplete/Suggetion box and search results.
When searched using full title of missing document set it shows in  Autocomplete/Suggetion as well as in results.

For Example : I did search for XYZ string. I have XYZ-ABC, XYZ-DEF, XYZ-GHI, XYZ-JKL, XYZ-MNO, XYZ-PQR documents sets in document library. Autocomplete/Suggetion box and search results shows XYZ-ABC, XYZ-DEF, XYZ-JKL, XYZ-PQR and skips XYZ-GHI and XYZ-MNO randomly.

When I search using full name of document sets like XYZ-GHI, XYZ-MNO it is displayed in Autocomplete/Suggetion box and search results.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

When troubleshooting something like this there is a lot that can be in play. Ensure that you are using a proper test case as there should be nothing "random" about the results. I would also seperate the Search Results issue from the Query Suggestions issue.

- Are all of the documents unique? If not, de-duplication may be in play.
- Is the index up to date? Often it's best to reset the index and run a full crawl when performing test cases
- How are you generating your suggestions? Are you doing it manually or letting SharePoint do it. If SharePoint, your clicks and the associated timer jobs matter.
- Do you have the Complete Matching attribute set for your Managed Property, if so this will defeat attempts at partial matching. This should not be the case for Title if you are using the OOB Managed Property.

HTH,

Matt